# What is the order of fields in an inherited class?

Tags: c++11, memory

```
struct A {int a;};
struct B : A {int b;};
B b;
```

Does the Standard guarantee how are the fields ordered in memory i.e. does `a` come before `b` and is there any padding?

---

Use case. I have `class Specification` and `class Command`. The command objects include a specification in them, as well as some additional information. I want to be able to use an object of either type when a `Specification` is required.

This use case is quite naive - be sure to read all comments below the question. Still the original question is interesting for other reasons: pointer arithmetic, buffer overruns, caching patterns and decompilation come to mind.

Comment: How is your use case related to your question?

Comment: in teh code above, object of Type B ensures that it includes members of struct A, i-e int a; during its construction. First the members of Super Class are created then member of Sub will be created according to scenario you provided.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the fields in `Command` should be ordered in a specific way (because `Command` objects are being de/serialized for communication purposes). The members from `Command` are part of that ordering and I would like to know can I reliably insert field before and after the inherited fields.

Comment: Why don't you explain that *in the question*?

Comment: My 2 cents: don't rely on member order for serializing.  Do your own marshalling (or use a library) to make sure you follow the protocol.

Comment: @Vorac Why does physical memory layout even bothers you? Take members by name/symbol for de/serialization purposes. Taking a simple memory dump is not a good way for this, it will get you in troubles sooner or later. If you want it robust you should not couple serialized representation with hard-wire memory layout.

Comment: @luk32, I am sending/receiving things over `void*`. The simplest solution is to rely on the memory layout of a structure and cast the pointer to that.

Comment: @Vorac Even if you send data as `void*` you should not send memory dumps of your objects. You should send a serialized object. Taking a memory dump is not a good way to serialize. What would you do if bit endianess would change from the source to target system? I know it is a convenient way but it is not reliable.

Comment: @luk32, the platform is fixed and will not change. However, I acknowledge my lack of knowledge on the subject of serialization. Please, if you have handy any introductory articles or online books, do drop a link or two.

Comment: Found the answer. As expected: `Boost.Serialization`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> Does the Standard guarantee how are the fields ordered in memory i.e. does `a` come before `b` and is there any padding?

The standard does not make any such guarantee. It leaved those details to the implementation. From the C++ Draft Standard (N3337):

> **10 Derived Classes**
>
> 5 The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object (1.8) is unspecified. [ *Note:* a derived class and its base class subobjects can be represented by a directed acyclic graph (DAG) where an arrow means “directly derived from.” A DAG of subobjects is often referred to as a “subobject
>   lattice.”

```
            Base
             ^
             |
          Derived1
             ^
             |
          Derived2
```

> 6 The arrows need not have a physical representation in memory. — *end note* ]

While the standard does not guarantee it, I haven't seen an implementation that does not do what you are expecting. There may be some in the wild but I haven't seen them.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was asking for. I decided to go with composition, despite the need for a little boilerplate code. Plus study the concept of serialization, as per **luk32**'s comment to my question.

Comment: In C++20 it's clause 5 of Section 11.7 Derived classes[class.derived]. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.derived#5

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like what you want is polymorphism (either create a base class `Specification` or just some interface class, i.e. an abstract base class), whatever better fits your use case. Pretty much what you're doing already:

```
class Specification {
    int a;
}

class Command : public Specificaion {
    // int a; is essentially here, inherited from Specification
    int b;
}

// later on:
Specification *mySpec = new Specification();

mySpec->a = 5; // valid

delete mySpec;
mySpec = new Command();
mySpec->a = 60; // valid as well
```

As long as you're working with pointers of the base class, you're basically going "from top to bottom" when looking up members. It's a bit more complicated than that, but since you're obviously using C++, you shouldn't just try casting unrelated types and hope that members are aligned the same way. If you need some way to read/write the classes to/from files, create some member to do the serialization in a clearly defined way.

Comment: Polymorphism... or not. Maybe avoiding inheritance (often abused) and using composition suffices if the types have standard layout

Answer (score 0):

- Does 'a' come before 'b' - YES
- Is there any padding? - Depends on compiler/pragma/alignment settings. And it depends on compiler/IDE how to setup packing/alignment (although new standards have some new keywords).

Comment: Can you please quote the standard, that in memory a derived class is before base? As far as I can recall order of fields and padding is totally up to compiler. I am not even sure if Base has to be monolithic (it probably is) but if compiler would decide it is easier to put additional member in front of Base, I imagine it is allowed to do so.

Comment: Don't have copy of standards. How would 'Object Slicing' and inheritance would work of 'a' cannot/may not appear before 'b' ?

Comment: What is the difference if A is before B or after? Slicing would work in exactly the same way as it does. It is about the offset from the base. You would either add it or substract it. I honestly don't see a big problem in putting derived members in front of a base class. Can you make up a simple example that disproves it? Slicing would be problematic if derived class would be allowed to be split, that is why I said it probably is monolithic. Also the questions is not, how would it work, but is it allowed. There is a big difference IMO.

Comment: The class 'A' would be base class of umpteen classes. There is class 'Z1'. How the compiler going to distinguish that 3rd member of 'Z1' is appearing before all members of 'A' - if reference of A is needed and object of `Z1` is passed. Since reference of 'A' is needed, some 'N' class may also be passed.

Comment: Why would compiler need to distinguish any "if"s? It would state that the memory layout is B|A and not A|B when it comes to inheritance. There is no problem, because at the linking all offsets can be calculated. Nevermind, there is an answer that quotes standard, saying order is not guaranteed, so I think your 1st statement is not correct.

Comment: -1, the standard explicitly says the order is not specified. It is perfectly possible to create a conforming compiler where `b` comes before `a`.

Comment: Ajay you are missing the point when thinking about *slicing*. The problem of slicing is that `B::operator=(B const&)` is called where you have `b = d`, when the overload is selected, the compiler must obtain a `Base const&` from the `d` object and that is either a noop (if the base is aligned with the object) or applying an offset if they are not. Note that this is already the case if the inheritance relationship is `virtual`, and in that case it is not even known at compile time!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Now I understand what 'offset' luk32 was talking about.  Thanks!